# not adding pins in firebase iteration

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm trying to add pins from a firebase database into a mapview, so i've done a little testing by trying following code to add into a map, which works fine:

```
    var array:[FBAnnotation] = []

    let pinTwo = FBAnnotation(name: "test", image: "test", desc: "test", longitude: 57.18506643076407, latitude: 9.78643024224879)
    array.append(pinTwo!)

    let pinOne = FBAnnotation(name: "test", image: "test", desc: "test", longitude: 57.18506643076407, latitude: 9.78643024224879)
    array.append(pinOne!)

    self.clusteringManager.addAnnotations(array)
```

However when I paste the exact same code into following code it doesn't add the pins. What can trigger this? I've double checked that the code print `test` 1 time, so it should work?

```
           let spots = rootRef.child("spots")
           spots.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                for item in snapshot.children {
                    print("test")
                }
            })
```

Here is what it looks like when i merge them and it do not add any pins. it seems like it cant add pins in the block?

```
            spots.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

                var array:[FBAnnotation] = []

                    let pinTwo = FBAnnotation(name: "test", image: "test", desc: "test", longitude: 57.18506643076407, latitude: 9.78643024224879)
                    array.append(pinTwo!)

                    let pinOne = FBAnnotation(name: "test", image: "test", desc: "test", longitude: 57.18506643076407, latitude: 9.78643024224879)
                    array.append(pinOne!)

                 self.clusteringManager.addAnnotations(array)
            })
```